# Nav menu walker for multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, css, navbar

This is my code:

```
public static function display_menu(){
        printf('<nav id="menu" class="column small-10">
                        %s
                </nav>', self::get_mobile_menu()
        );
}

public static function get_mobile_menu(){
    if( false === ( $mobile_menu = get_transient(self::MENUMOBILE_TRANSIENT_NAME) )){
        $mobile_menu_args = array(
                'theme_location'  => 'mobile',
                'echo'            => false,
                'container'       => '',
                'container_class' => '',
                'container_id'    => '',
                'menu_class'      => 'right',
                'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                'walker'          => new Mobile_Menu_Walker()
        );
        $mobile_menu = wp_nav_menu($mobile_menu_args);
        set_transient( self::MENUMOBILE_TRANSIENT_NAME, $mobile_menu, self::MENU_TRANSIENT_TIME );
    }
    return $mobile_menu;
}
```

If I switch to ENG version, the Walker nav create a menu with a `div class="right"` and `ul` without class... Why? in ITA version, it works!

The function `"display_menu"` is called into `header.php`

Comment: What are you using to change from English to Italian? Is there a plugin in the middle?

Comment: Yes, Any Mobile Theme Switcher : https://wordpress.org/plugins/any-mobile-theme-switcher/

The code is the same for ITA and ENG version


PS: My site works with W3 Total Cache and Any Mobile works with W3TC only if I've W3TC Premium

Comment: That plugin detects what browser you are using, not what language. Im not too sure how exactly your doing the change of language but my guess would be that if you are using that as the language changer, it is not calling in the template or functions correctly for the specified page

Comment: Mmm, it's possibile! But I don't know how it create " div class="right" " and not  " ul class="right" "